# Как организовать выполнимый код в редакторах типа MCE и т.п.?

Tags: jquery, php, eval, javascript

Допустим создаю я статью по `javascript` и хочу для примера показать какие-то дей-я, стандартно это все просто в самом редакторе делается и выводится результат как обычный текст и т.п., а вот как сделать чтобы пользователь мог т.с. руками пощупать какой-то клик? Ясное дело что все это можно через `eval` зачудить, но сама логика пока не понятна мне как такое воплотить в `Real Life`.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте попробуем написать скрипт, позволяющий это делать здесь, средствами UserJS.
Описывать основы пользовательских скриптов я не буду, и приступлю сразу к работе.

В блоке "отформатированный текст", местный редактор заворачивает код в тег `<code>` и каждый значащий "словосимвол" в `<span>`. Что ж, приступим.
Для начала найдем DOM элементы с тегом `<code>`:

```
var parent = typeof unsafeWindow != 'undefined' ? unsafeWindow : window;
var root = parent.document;
var codes = root.getElementsByTagName('code');
```

Теперь для каждого элемента codes прикрутим кнопку для запуска кода.

```
for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++)
    if (codes[i].parentNode.getAttribute('class') == 'prettyprint') {
        var runBtn = root.createElement('img');
        runBtn.setAttribute('src','http://htmlbook.ru/themes/hb/images/win.gif');
        runBtn.setAttribute('style','position:relative; top:-15px; left:90%; cursor:pointer;');
        codes[i].parentNode.appendChild(runBtn);
        runBtn.addEventListener('click',runCode,false);
    }
```

И напишем к ним обработчик, который будет открывать новое окно, содержащее отфильтрованный от тегов и спецсимволов скрипт:

```
function runCode(e){
    var code = codeFree(e.target.previousSibling.innerHTML);
    var br = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    infoWind = parent.open('temp.html', 'Выполнение скрипта', 'width=200,height=150,toolbar=no,top='+br.top+',left='+br.left);
    infoWind.document.write('<script>'+code+'</script>');
}
function codeFree(cd){
    while (/(<\/span>)?(<span class="[a-z]+">)/.test(cd))
        cd = cd.replace(/(<\/span>)?(<span class="[a-z]+">)/,'');
    cd = cd.replace(/<\/span>/,'');
    while (/&nbsp;/.test(cd))
        cd = cd.replace(/&nbsp;/,' ');
    while (/<br>/.test(cd))
        cd = cd.replace(/<br>/,'\n');
    while (/\&lt\;\/?script\&gt\;/.test(cd))
        cd = cd.replace(/\&lt\;\/?script\&gt\;/,'\n');
    return cd;
}
```

Все очень просто и понятно.
Исходник: http://files.mail.ru/Z6ON8O